# Overflow while trying to bind NaN

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

My Table schema is:

```
desc TRNX_TXN_MAP_VALUES
Name                Null     Type            
------------------- -------- --------------- 
BASE_TRANSACTION_ID NOT NULL NUMBER(19)      
MAP_TYPE            NOT NULL VARCHAR2(2)     
ENUM_TYPE           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)    
DECIMALVALUE                 NUMBER(12,2)    
STRINGVALUE                  VARCHAR2(100)   
LONGVALUE                    NUMBER(19)      
BOOLEANVALUE                 NUMBER(1)       
DOUBLEVALUE                  NUMBER(38,2)    
CURRENCYCODE                 VARCHAR2(20)    
AMOUNT                       NUMBER(18,2)    
DOUBLEARRAY                  DOUBLE_VARRAY()
```

While storing certain values I am getting following exception:
It seems that some values have a very large precision and the column it gets mapped to does support it. Is this possible? I am using Oracle 11g as my Database and Spring JdbcTemple to persist things.

```
TRACE StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [1264684185], value class [java.lang.Long], SQL type -5
TRACE StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 2, parameter value [P], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type 12
TRACE StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 3, parameter value [MTM], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type 12
TRACE StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 4, parameter value [null], value class [null], SQL type 3
TRACE StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 5, parameter value [null], value class [null], SQL type 12
TRACE StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 6, parameter value [null], value class [null], SQL type -5
TRACE StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 7, parameter value [null], value class [null], SQL type 4
TRACE StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 8, parameter value [null], value class [null], SQL type 8
TRACE StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 9, parameter value [USD], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type 12
TRACE StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 10, parameter value [-287.0004000000008], value class [java.lang.Double], SQL type 8
TRACE StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [1264684185], value class [java.lang.Long], SQL type -5
TRACE StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 2, parameter value [P], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type 12
TRACE StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 3, parameter value [POTENTIAL_EXPOSURE], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type 12
TRACE StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 4, parameter value [null], value class [null], SQL type 3
TRACE StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 5, parameter value [null], value class [null], SQL type 12
TRACE StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 6, parameter value [null], value class [null], SQL type -5
TRACE StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 7, parameter value [null], value class [null], SQL type 4
TRACE StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 8, parameter value [751.1283787024478], value class [java.lang.Double], SQL type 8
TRACE StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 9, parameter value [null], value class [null], SQL type 12
TRACE StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 10, parameter value [null], value class [null], SQL type 8
INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader  - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
INFO  SQLErrorCodesFactory  - SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase]
ERROR LoggingHandler  - org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [Insert into TRNX_TXN_MAP_VALUES (BASE_TRANSACTION_ID,MAP_TYPE,ENUM_TYPE,DECIMALVALUE,STRINGVALUE,LONGVALUE,BOOLEANVALUE,DOUBLEVALUE,CURRENCYCODE,AMOUNT) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Overflow Exception trying to bind NaN; nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Overflow Exception trying to bind NaN
```

Comment: Its doing some operation until a condition on NaN is met, but since it doesn't handle NaN correctly it never meets the condition.  Just a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was a data issue, Double object actually allows to do something like sqrt(-ve number). It stores it as NaN and oracle shouts while storing it.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem. And I find nothing wrong in the data.
I found the answer ： [sql-hibernate-erreur-overflow-exception-trying-to-bind-nan-lis-objet](https://www.developpez.net/forums/d1340268/java/general-java/jdbc/sql-hibernate-erreur-overflow-exception-trying-to-bind-nan-lis-objet/)

But the answer is written in French. Probably it means this problem may be cause by hibernate cache. So I do  below things

```
1. Clean The Tomcat Server
2. Clean the project
```

and finally, It works for me!!